# Ionic and Angularjs view navigation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to using angularjs and am having a difficult time having angular route to a new page to load. Essentially I am trying to figure out how to move between pages to build a multi page app but I keep receiving this error even though I have created the module.

Module 'login.html' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

these are my index.html and my app.js files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-           

scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the    
CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app='login.html'>
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

app.js File:

```
// Ionic Starter App

var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

$stateProvider.state('login', {
url: '/',
templateURL: 'login.html'
})
})
```

login.html

```
<ion-view title=""id="welcome-view" hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content>
<div  class="logo-welcome"></div>
<div class="login-btns">
<div id="social-links">
<ul>
<li ng-click="fbLogin()"><span class="ifacebook"><img src="img/social-   
icons/facebook.png"></span><a href="#" class="afacebook">sign in with   
facebook</a></li>
<li ng-click="gplusLogin()"><span class="igoogleplus"><img src="img/social- 
icons/googleplus.png"></span><a href="#" class="agoogleplus">sign in with   
google+</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<hr id="login-divider" />
<div id="login-reg">
<button id="btn-login" class="button button-clear button-positive   
uppercase">Login</button>
<button id="btn-reg" class="button button-clear button-positive   
uppercase">Register</button>
</div>
</div>
</ion-content>
<div id="footer" class="bar bar-footer">
<div class="title em-footer-title">© TechieDreams</div>
</div>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Error is in index.html file,

use ng-app name in the body as following,

```
<body ng-app="ionicApp">
```

That app name should use in app.js file,

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
```

Because, this is the root element of the angular js which help to executes our app.Reference : http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-app.asp

Answer (score 0):

You error is in your main HTML

change `<div ng-app='login.html'>` to `<div ng-app='ionicApp'>` as described into your first JS file

Answer (score 0):

In your body tag add `ng-app ="ionicApp"`